Testing HttpInterceptorFn with rxjs retry operator
I'm trying to do some unit tests for my retry policy with the new interceptor function that Angular 17 provides.
Here is the interceptor code:
import { HttpErrorResponse, HttpInterceptorFn, HttpStatusCode } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RetryConfig, retry, throwError, timer } from 'rxjs';

const retryOnStatusCodes = [HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError];

const retryRequestOptions = {
  maximumRetries: 2,
  retryDelay: 1000
};

export const retryInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req, next) => {

  const retryConfig: RetryConfig =
  {
    count: retryRequestOptions.maximumRetries,
    resetOnSuccess: true,
    delay: (error: HttpErrorResponse, retryCount: number) =>
      retryOnStatusCodes.includes(error.status) ? timer(retryCount * retryRequestOptions.retryDelay) : throwError(() => error)
  };

  return next(req).pipe(retry(retryConfig));
};

And here is the .spec.ts file for my interceptor:
import { HttpHandlerFn, HttpInterceptorFn, HttpRequest, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { count, of } from 'rxjs';
import { retryInterceptor } from './retry.interceptor';

describe('retryInterceptor', () => {

  const interceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req, next) =>
    TestBed.runInInjectionContext(() => retryInterceptor(req, next));

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({});
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(interceptor).toBeTruthy();
  });

  fit('should retry when status code is 500', () => {

    // Call the interceptor
    const httpRequest = new HttpRequest<any>('GET', 'http://localhost:9876');
    const handlerFn: HttpHandlerFn = (req: HttpRequest<any>) => {
      return of(new HttpResponse<any>({ status: 500, statusText: 'error' }))
    }

    const observable = interceptor(httpRequest, handlerFn);

    const result = observable.pipe(count());

    result.subscribe(timesCalled => {
      expect(timesCalled).toBe(3);
    });
  })
});

The problem is that I'm incapable of asserting that the request has been made 3 times as the interceptor logic says.
I've tried running the application in localhost and making a request to a fake API that returns a 500 status code and the interceptor works fine, but, as said, I'm not doing something right in the code to test this in the right way.
